# Python pandas transpose data issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble figuring out how to properly transpose data in a DataFrame in order to calculate differences between actuals and targets. Doing something like: 
 `df['difference'] = df['Revenue'] - df['Target']`, 
 is straightforward so this is more a question of desired output formatting.

Assume you have a DataFrame with the follow columns and values:

[image]

Desire outputs would be a roll up from both sources and comparison at the `Source` level. Assume there are 30+ additional data points similar to revenue, users, and new users...[image] :

and

[image]

Any and all suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2016-06-01', 15000, 10000, 1000, 900, 100, 50, 'US'],
        ['2016-06-01', 16000, 12000, 1500, 1200, 150, 100, 'UK']
    ], columns=['Date', 'Revenue', 'Target', 'Users', 'Target', 'New Users', 'Target', 'Source'])
df
```

[image]

Your columns are not unique.  I'll start with moving `Source` and `Date` into the index and renaming the columns.

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
df1 = df1.set_index(['Date', 'Source'])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Revenue', 'Users', 'New Users'], ['Actual', 'Target']])
df1.columns = idx
df1
```

[image]

Then move the first level of `columns` to the `index`

```
df1 = df1.stack(0)
df1
```

[image]

From here, I'm going to sum sources across `['Revenue', 'Users', 'New Users']` and assign the result to `df2`.

```
df2 = df1.groupby(level=-1).sum()
df2
```

[image]

Finally:

```
df2['Difference'] = df2.Actual / df2.Target
df1['Difference'] = df1.Actual / df1.Target

df2
```

[image]

```
df1.stack().unstack([0, 1, -1])
```

[image]